# Apply scroll to browser instead of table in jquery flexigrid

Tags: jquery, css, flexigrid

hello i am using [flexigrid plugin](http://www.flexigrid.info/) for making Lightweight but rich data grid.

you can find the working demo on plugin site.

like this

```
$('#tblMatrixView').flexigrid({ height: 'auto', showToggleBtn: false, singleSelect: true });
```

where **tblMatrixView** is my table id

it's awesome but i am stuck with a problem that when re sizing column it is giving horizontal scroll to table but i want to give scroll to browser window instead.

how to accomplish this thing i am trying from 2-3 days but no success.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting style property like this

```
style="position:absolute;overflow:auto;"
```

for the outer-most div work for me